# Server session managment in Java

Tags: java, session, gwt, servlets

How can I handle static varibles inside my server session?

I have 30 different functions with no real realtion on the server, but they currently share data over some static varibles (I know this is bad, but I was just testing it). Now if I have different clients connecting to the server, they would interfear with each other an no client would get the right data.

So I wondered what a good way to handle this diferent Session datas without passing twenty refernce to the other objects to a class when creating a class.

Another problem is, that the classes instanciate threads, so I can't be shure, that the actions are completed when I send the responses back to the server. (So switchin the current static varibles depending on the client is not an option)

Comment: Do you use the static variables to determine wether your threads are completed? Help me understand why you still need static variables :)

Comment: I want to retag this question with something other than just [java].  Is [j2ee] appropriate?  Or is there something specific to the web server like [weblogic] or [struts] or something?

Comment: @ Bart Vangeneugden: using static varibles was easy because I didn't had to pass 20 varibles around, when I needed it in a class I just accessed the static varible (so there are things like the height of the client window... etc)

Comment: @Erick Robertson: Dunno, depending on the answers I guess...

Comment: @Erick: OP is likely talking about the Servlet API. `HttpSession` and on.

Comment: Unfortunately, SingleThreadModel won't work for this; not that anyone should be encouraged to use that anyway.

Comment: btw, I'm not programming a severlet, I'm programming the client code for an GWT application, if that makes any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to put all these things in the session (`session.setAttribute(..)` and `.getAttribute()`) then perhaps you can use a map of maps:

```
public static Map<String, Map<String, Object>> sessionValues = ...
```

and set/get from that map. Where:

- the key of the 1st map is the session id (can be obtained via `session.getId()`
- the key of the 2nd map is the property name
- the value of the 2nd map is the property value

Thus you will be able to have values unique to sessions without relying on the servlet API.

Comment: the problem with this is, that not evey class has the sessionID... (or have they)

Comment: you will have to pass it around. It's one string param, so it shouldn't be a problem. You _have to_ identify the session somehow, servlet or not.

Comment: I do that, but if I pass around the sessionID I could also pass around a class conatining all shared fields (which would then only be a reference so in fact would be faster)

Comment: yes, that's a good option as well if it doesn't violate layer boundaries

Comment: what do you mean by violate layer boundaries?

Comment: if, for example, you don't want your object to be accessible in the web layer.

Comment: ok, so I have to watch that my code matches the model I created before makeing writting it. OK, I'll watch that